# How do I log in to the IntelliJ IDEA TeamCity Plugin when TeamCity uses oAuth?

Tags: intellij-idea, teamcity

I have downloaded the TeamCity plugin for IntelliJ IDEA and I am trying to log into it.

The login dialog of the plugin requires a username and password:

[image]

Our TeamCity is authenticated via oAuth, so I don't have a password as such.

How can I authenticate via the plugin? Is there some token I can generate? And if so, do I just enter the token into the password box? I couldn't see anywhere else that would accept a token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the TeamCity Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA does not support OAuth.

You have to create the user in the TC.

Comment: The answer is correct. There is a feature request in the issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-55292

Answer (score 4):

You may generate an access token in **My Settings & Tools | Access Tokens** and use it as a password in this login dialog.
See [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/managing-your-user-account.html#Managing-Access-Tokens) for details on how to generate access token in TeamCity.

Comment: It sounds really unintuitive but works. Standard login/password auth worked fine before ~2021.1 TC versions. This seems like solution for all newer versions